# accessing enums in a COM object [jscript]

Tags: com, enums, itunes, javascript, itunes-sdk

How do I access an enum that is defined within a COM interface?  Specifically, I've created a new instance of an iTunes.Application:

```
var   iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
```

... and I want to be able to use certain enums defined within the COM

> **iTunesTrackCOM.idl File Reference**
>   [...]
>   **Enumerations**
>   [...]

```
enum   ITVideoKind { 
   ITVideoKindNone = 0, 
   ITVideoKindMovie, 
   ITVideoKindMusicVideo, 
   ITVideoKindTVShow 
 }
```

I've tried iTunesApp.ITVideoKindTVShow, but that doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, how could I root around the iTunesApp object interactively via a shell or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the enum by name.  You have to just use the constants: 0, 1, 2...

It's really awesome when you're dealing with bit-fields.  You have to use the decimal value of the bit-flag, e.g. the `flags` parameter to [IHTMLTxtRange::findText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741525(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Or declare your own constants in the scripts, and use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers; this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like tlb2const to generate constants from the typelib.

See my answer here:
[Is it possible to expose a C# Enum to COM Interop callers, and if so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276442/is-it-possible-to-expose-a-c-enum-to-com-interop-callers-and-if-so-how/1276503#1276503)